# Celestron logic drive precision DC motor drive

Tags: switches

I am having issues trying to integrate a simple mini DC voltmeter panel onto this circuit board in regards to having it wired up so it is only powered when the ON switch is active/motor running.

The item itself functions as expected, but the wiring from my basic understanding doesn't seem right. For example, the OFF/ON switch being soldered as pairs different to the N/S switch. I therefore am unable to use the OFF/ON switch as an indicator/toggle for powering the voltmeter panel as it always receives power but in the OFF state the motor doesn't run.

There are many schematics available online but I no clue how to read them or what to look for.

I probed the board using a voltmeter in continuity mode trying to find/understand an open/closed circuit toggle for the board. Apart from the N/S switch I was unsuccessful.

[image: Plastic cover]

[image: Board 01]

[image: Board 02]

[image: Board 03 - close up]

[image: Schematics]

Comment: why are you not sharing a schematic diagram?

Comment: @jsotola As I stated in my query I am not familiar with reading schematics/terminology used unfortunately. Able to identify the schematics posted by comparing the components as thankfully they are labelled on the circuit board as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place you can connect the power to the voltmeter so that is turned on and off by the switch is here:

[image]

Looking at the back of the circuit board, that would be here:

[image]